# How to set text content Custom TextView in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, textview

I just create custom TextView in Kotlin named MyTextView and XML layout also.

```
 class MyTextView : TextView 
{
 constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
 {
     init()
 }

 constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)
 {
     init()
 }

 constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
 {
     init()
 }

 private fun init()
 {
     this.paintFlags = this.paintFlags or Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG
 }
}
```

```
<com.mypackage.MyTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mytextview"
/>
```

But when I tried to set text like below

```
mytextview.text = "hi"
```

it says, unresolved reference. What to do?

It works for normal TextView.

Comment: it's just completely weird to think about a custom TextView... can you not just create a TextView in the Layout and then create a reference  for that TextView by findViewById and then try chaging the text by setText ?

Comment: What is the id of your customTextView? is it `mytextview`?

Comment: Please post your xml layout.

Comment: yes... id is mytextview and I am using extensions @sanoJ

Comment: I have pasted my xml layout code

Comment: Do your imports have `kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.mytextview` ? If not try to add it.

Comment: Yes. I have import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you're not referencing the package name for your custom TextView in the layout and the activity inflater has no idea where to find that view (your custom TextView). Make sure you have referenced the package name in your layout like below:

```
<your.package.name.MyCustomTextView />
```

and make sure you set the `id` attribute

```
<your.package.name.MyCustomTextView android:id="@+id/mytextview" />
```

Comment: @MikeM. hhhahaa just spotted it...spell-checking and autocorrect trying to fix my typos

Comment: It's all done. but not working. Please look above, I have added the code

Comment: I am using android extensions

Comment: @Emilyjohn the same concept still applies. You will find the package name at the top of your custom textview's code file..

Answer (score 0):

please import layout file first

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.layout_name.mytextview
```

you need editable instance for set text to textview

please try this for kotlin

```
mytextview.text = Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable("hi")
```

Comment: There's no need for this. A literal string should work out of the box

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
val textView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.android_text) as TextView
textView.setOnClickListener {
textView.text = getString(R.string.name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
var mytextview = findViewById(R.id.mytextview) as TextView
```

After that you can try like this like java:

```
Toast.makeText(this, mytextview.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

I hope It help you!